# Projection associated to the decomposition $H=M⊕N$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $M$ and $N$ be two closed subspaces in $H$ such that $H=M⊕N$.

I'm trying to find a formula giving $P_{M,N}$ (the projection onto $M$ with respect to $N$) in terms of $P_{M,M^{\bot }}$ (the orthogonal projection onto $M$) and $P_{N,N^{\bot }}$ (the orthogonal projection onto $N$).

Thank you !

Comment: Does $H=M⊕N$ denote an *orthogonal* direct sum? And what is meant by
"the projection onto $M$ with respect to $N$"? Furthermore, the notation
"$P_{M,M^\bot}$" is ambiguous because a projector is tied to its image space, and that relationship becomes 1-to-1 only for orthogonal projections.

Comment: @Hanno: any direct sum defines projections (relative to the sum).

Comment: @MartinArgerami This settles my 2nd question, thanks. And hints at an answer to the 1st one: Direct sum is *not orthogonal*, otherwise "the formula" would reduce to
 $P_{M,M^\bot}$, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $ $

Comment: By $P_{M,N}$ I mean a projection such that $P_{M,N}\left( M\right) =M$ and $
P_{M,N}\left( N\right) =\left\{ 0\right\} $

The direct sum $\oplus $ is not necessarily orthogonal.

The projection $P_{M,M^{\bot }}$ is orthogonal, because $P_{M,M^{\bot
}}\left( M^{\bot }\right) =\left\{ 0\right\} $.

I've found the formula $P_{M,N}=P_{M,M^{\bot }}\left( I-P_{N,N^{\bot
}}P_{M,M^{\bot }}\right) ^{-1}\left( I-P_{N,N^{\bot }}\right) $ but i'm not
sure it's always defined.

Thanks for comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to write $\,Q=P_{M,M^\perp}$ and $\,R=P_{N,N^\perp}$ for the orthogonal projections.

Loosely speaking, $P_{M,N}$ and $Q$ have eigenvalue multiplicities which coincide. Moreover, they possess the same supporting subspace
$\,M=\operatorname{im}P_{M,N}=\operatorname{im}Q=\,$ the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$. So let's look out for a similarity transformation $T$ intertwining them, i.e.
$$TP_{M,N}=Q\,T\tag{1}$$ 
with $T$ invertible.

Necessarily, $T$ has to map $N$ to $\ker Q = M^\perp$,
and this is fulfilled by choosing $T=\mathbb 1-QR\,$:
$$Tn \:=\: (\mathbb 1-QR)n \:=\: n-Qn \:=\: (\mathbb 1-Q)n\:\in M^\perp\quad\forall n\in N,$$
hence $(1)$ is satisfied when restricted to $N$.
For $m\in M$ the RHS evaluates to $$QTm \:=\: (Q-QR)m \:=\: m-QRm \:=\: Tm\,,$$
and $(1)$ is again satisfied, hence it's satisfied in general.
$T=\mathbb 1-QR\,$ is invertible because $\|QR\|<1$, which in turn follows(*) from
the central assumption $H=M\oplus N=\operatorname{im}Q\oplus\operatorname{im}R\,$.
Thus,
$$P_{M,N}\:=\:(\mathbb 1-QR)^{-1}Q\,(\mathbb 1-QR)\tag{2}$$ 
is a formula as asked for.

<sub>* [Norm estimate for a product of two orthogonal projectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3092323/316749)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela It was fun (in the end), I really liked to work on this one, with all the oblique stuff around! How and/or where did you find the formula contained in your comment above?

Comment: I've constructed it after an infinite step of decomposition. I've obtained a formula that I was able to simplify in some way and finally obtained it.

Comment: Then the correct formula is : $P_{M,N}=\left( I-P_{M,M^{\bot }}P_{N,N^{\bot }}\right)^{-1}P_{M,M^{\bot }}\left( I-P_{N,N^{\bot }}\right)$

Comment: I would say *a correct formula*, not "the", supposedly there are more.

Comment: Yes , but QxQ=Q